# Order of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getSupportedLocales()

Tags: jsf

I have inherited a database model where every table has 3 columns: _lg1, _lg2, _lg3; for 3 languages (I know...)

Anyway, I was wondering if by defining the supported locales of my JSF application I can map these three columns to their corresponding languages.

In other words: Is [FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getSupportedLocales()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getSupportedLocales--) supposed to return an Iterator for the supported locales to traverse them in the same order they are defined in faces-config.xml?

Otherwise I would have to do this mapping somewhere else, which is a little redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is nowhere defined in the spec or the javadoc. In Mojarra, it's [internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/config/processor/ApplicationConfigProcessor.java#837) stored as a `HashSet<Locale>`. So, the order is absolutely undefined over there.

Your best bet is defining it elsewhere. E.g. a context param, or even a resource bundle entry. A completely different alternative is parsing the `faces-config.xml` yourself in order to collect them. As per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/465a78dab39611033e8ef140225416834de86cca), it will be available in [OmniFaces 2.2](http://omnifaces.org) as below:

```
List<Locale> supportedLocales = FacesConfigXml.INSTANCE.getSupportedLocales();
```